# Wordpress meta key search combined with post title search using WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do my own custom search that looks at both meta keys and the post title.

My current code does not limit the results to the category assigned (due to the `OR` in the query). However by making it `AND` then search in the meta keys stop working unless the word is in the title.

Is there a way I can search both the titles and meta keys and still limit it to that category?

**EDIT :** Just to clarify,
The search im looking to do is the following:

*Search the search term either in those meta fields or in the post title but all results MUST be in that category.*

```
                    function search_title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ) {
                        global $wpdb;
                        if ( $search_title = $_GET['search-in-main-category'] ) {
                            $where .= ' OR ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $search_title ) ) . '%\'';
                        }

                        return $where;
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['search-in-main-category'])) {

                        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'search_title_filter', 10, 2 );
                        $search_key = $_GET['search-in-main-category'];
                        $query_args = array(
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'course_overview',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'intended_audience',
                                'value' => $search_key,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'method_of_delivery',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'course_content/agenda',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                )),
                            'product_cat' => $current_cat_slug,
                            'posts_per_page' => 50
                            );
                        $search_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding more code to my custom SQL. The only way I could get the variable into the function was using a global variable.

```
                    global $current_cat;
                    $current_cat = $current_cat_id;
                    function search_title_filter( $where, &$wp_query) {
                        global $wpdb;
                        global $current_cat;
                        if ( $search_title = $_GET['search-in-main-category'] ) {
                            $where .= ' OR ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $search_title ) ) . '%\'
                            AND '.$wpdb->term_relationships.'.term_taxonomy_id = '.$current_cat;
                        }

                        return $where;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, you mention category as being in the relation setting of wp_query? this is not the case and you have a issue with your category key, unless it is actually called product_cat, its not correct, but even if correct it has been depreciated (see tax_query below)

My nearest guess is you are asking how to combine relationships within the meta query fields which are as follows:

```
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'course_overview',
            'value' => $search_key,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'intended_audience',
            'value' => $search_key,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
              'relation' => 'AND',  
              array(
                    'key' => 'method_of_delivery',
                    'value' => $search_key,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'course_content/agenda',
                    'value' => $search_key,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                )
        ),   


    ),
```

As you can see there is a new array and relationship of `AND` specified.

As for category you have 2 different types, one is the inbuilt category taxonomy and you can use `cat` = id of the category, `category_name` which is the slug name. You can see the codex for examples of this.

The custom taxonomy is for your own taxonomies (products is not an inbuilt taxonomy. You use tax_query for this which is similar to meta_query

```
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'phpcourse',
    ),
 ),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, sorry when I meant `OR` I meant in the search filter in the function in my code. I probably should have mentioned Im using woocommerce hence `product_cat` but thanks for that info its useful anyway

Answer (score 0):

You final query will be like this:

```
                          $query_args = array(
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                  array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'product',
                              'field'    => 'slug',
                              'terms'    => 'phpcourse',
                                   ),
                             ),
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'course_overview',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'intended_audience',
                                'value' => $search_key,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'method_of_delivery',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'course_content/agenda',
                                    'value' => $search_key,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                )),
                            'product_cat' => $current_cat_slug,
                            'posts_per_page' => 50
                            );
                        $search_query = new 

                       WP_Query( $query_args );
```